# java chat system,issue in sending & recieving

Tags: java, system, chat

My program is set & ready, the problem is within the server. When I clients send the message, where should it be stored at ? I tried using queue but didn't work, also tried to use a usual string register but it worked partially. I made a thread for the sending & a thread for storing, using "Read/write UTF". I would be more than grateful if somebody provided me with an algorithm , or at a least a better idea. Code :

```
class clientThread extends Thread {
    DataInputStream fromClient;
    int counter = 0;

    public clientThread(Socket cs) throws IOException
    {
        fromClient = new DataInputStream(cs.getInputStream());
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try {
                toall=Integer.toString(counter)+fromClient.readUTF();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ChatTerminalS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            counter++;
        }
    }
}

class SendingThread extends Thread
{
    DataOutputStream toClient;
    String s = "";int counter=0;

    public SendingThread(Socket cs) throws IOException
    {
        toClient = new DataOutputStream(cs.getOutputStream());
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if(toall.charAt(0)+""==Integer.toString(counter))
            {}
            else
            {
                try {
                    toClient.writeUTF(toall);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ChatTerminalS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of your empty if statement with the logic in the else you can just changed the == to a != if(toall.charAt(0)+""!=Integer.toString(counter))

Comment: Use an ArrayList<String> maybe? For answer me just add @Zecas to your comment please.